# How to clean iOS Device Console from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode-organizer

I have been looking for a solution, but I couldn't find any. Is there any way to clean **Device Console** from command line?

Normally, we do this going to **XCode -> Organizer -> Device -> Console -> Clear**.

Thanks

Comment: What XCode version do you use?

Comment: Ok, it's a little bit outdated. Could you, please, share some screenshots?